# Geocalização em cordova

Tags: apache-cordova

Estava usando o plugin do CORDOVA de geocalização, no computador dar tudo certo, mostra a latitude e longitude normal, mas quando eu testo no meu ANDROID não mostra a localização e aparece a mensagem:

code: 1 message:only secure origins are allowed (see: goo.gl/Y0ZkNV )

Por favor, alguém me ajuda.

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disso. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)). Se a solução for muito simples ainda é possível que alguém o faça nos comentários.

Comment: vai na documentação do plugin e veja com setar corretamente as permissões para uso da localização no dispositivo